# Characteristic Cauchy problem for 1st order pde

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

When the initial curve is characteristic, the Cauchy problem may have infinitly many solutions or no solution at all. In the case of existence of infinity of solutions, how to construct them?

Example: consider the  following Cauchy problem
$$
u_x+yu_y=0\\
u(x,0)=\cos(x)
$$

Comment: This example has the general solution $u(x,y)=F(ye^{-x})$, which means that $u(x,0)=F(0)$ would have to be constant for infinitely many solutions to exist.

Comment: You mean that my example has no solution?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. This equation needs $u=const.$ along the characteristic curves $x(s)=x_0+s$, $y(s)=y_0e^s$, $z(s)=z_0$.